# VS2013 - WebForm - Content page cannot be created because language not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms, visual-studio-2013

This is a default File > New Web Site > ASP.NET Web Forms Site C#.

I tried to right click on Site.master and then "Add Content Page".

I am getting the following error.

*The content page cannot be created because the language specified for the master page, 'C#', is not supported*

default Site.master page

I tried to download .net 4.5.1 and run repair.

I have tried this with .NET 4, 4.5, and 4.5.1 selected when creating new site.

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

System Info
Windows 7 64bit 
VS Pro 2013 12.0.30110.00 update 1
.net 4.5.50938

Comment: did you installed asp.net on iis?

Comment: Under IIS > WWS > App Dev I have: .net exten/asp.net/isapi ext/isapi filters turned on